# Preserve observable value when component is reloaded

Tags: angular, asynchronous, react-redux, rxjs, observable

I have an angular app (v5). On one of the pages there are two components (A and B). Component A has a grid which upon a cell click push the cell value to a rxjs subject. Component B subscribed to that subject and refresh its content accordingly. This flow works as expected until Component B is moved to a different routerlink.

Looking under the hood I can see that when the cell is clicked on component A, component B was indeed notified the change in its subscription (next) handler. Note at that time component B is not visible yet. When the component B is brought to visibility via the routerlink click it’s UI doesn’t reflect the value in the subject(observable).

1. Is the ‘visibility’ the issue?
2. Does the routerlink click cause component B to be reloaded and lose the data it captured from the subject?
3. Is the subject not the right type to facilitate such communication? I understand the routerlink can have parameters but that is not what I need. The updates to the subject can come from different sources besides component A. Component B needs to reflect the up to date info from the subject whenever it is brought to visibility.
4. What is the correct way to implement cross components async communization?

Comment: Could you do a plunker or stackblitz that demos your issue? I'm not clear on the details and it would help to see some of the code. In general, a Subject only emits items when they are provided. A BehaviorSubject emits the most recent item upon subscription. There are also other types of subjects you can find here: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html

Comment: Will try to create one. I was watching your routine course and hoping to find some clue!

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestion on the different subject type. it indeed fixed my problem.

Comment: Is this problem better solved via ngrx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BehaviourSubject in this scenario. BehaviourSubject emits last value. So when you will subscribe in component B it will recieve last value emited by component A.

Hope it will help